# Fully qualified name for .NET 4.0 assembly

Tags: .net-4.0, assemblies, httphandler, gac

I am having some problems getting my httpHandler working with an assembly deployed in the GAC.
My assembly is created in the .NET 4.0 Framework. Because of the .NET 4.0 framework my dll is not deployed to the C:\Windows\assembly but it is deployed to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL folder.
I tried to put the fully qualified name in my web.config but still when I try to open my webpage I get the error "assembly-name or codebase not valid"

Hopefully someone can give me tips to get my assembly in the C:\Windows\assembly or how I can make use of the dll that is deployed in the GAC_MSIL folder.

Thanks.